# BigQuery finding sessions that have visited both pageA (contains keyword "main") and pageB (contains keyword "side")

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

On BQ I'm trying to find sessions that have visited both pageA (URL contains keyword "main") and pageB (URL contains keyword "side"), and the pages that session visited.
Here is my logic, I first wanted to find out sessions that have visited pageAs (URL contains keyword "main"), then I wanted to do a join, so to find out those sessions who have visited pageAs, what else pages on the site have they visited. Below is my query:

```
select a. sessionID, b.pagepath
from 
(SELECT
CONCAT(fullVisitorID, CAST(visitID AS string), date) AS sessionID,
 hits.page.pagepath as pagepath
 FROM
`xx.xxx.ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
totals.visits = 1
and hits.page.pagepath like '%main%' 
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20220214'
AND '20220225') a
left join 
(SELECT
CONCAT(fullVisitorID, CAST(visitID AS string), date) AS sessionID,
 hits.page.pagepath as pagepath
FROM
`xx.xxx.ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
totals.visits = 1 
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20220214'
AND '20220225') b 
on a.sessionID=b.sessionID
order by 1 desc
```

I am attaching an example output here:

| sessionID | Pagepath |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | /main-size |
| 123 | /main-size |
| 456 | /main-size |
| 456 | /main-size |
| 456 | /side-hide |
| 456 | /side-build |
| 456 | /June-event |

In this case session 456 meets my condition because it has visited both page contains "main" and page contains "side", however I wonder through this output how I can query to only get below output:

| sessionID | Pagepath |
| --- | --- |
| 456 | /main-size |
| 456 | /main-size |
| 456 | /side-hide |
| 456 | /side-build |
| 456 | /June-event |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below query.

```sql
 SELECT * EXCEPT(path)
   FROM sample_table, UNNEST([REGEXP_EXTRACT(Pagepath, r'(main|side)')]) path
QUALIFY COUNT(DISTINCT path) OVER (PARTITION BY sessionID) = 2

-- Query results
+-----+-----------+-------------+
| Row | sessionID |  Pagepath   |
+-----+-----------+-------------+
|   1 |       456 | /main-size  |
|   2 |       456 | /main-size  |
|   3 |       456 | /side-hide  |
|   4 |       456 | /June-event |
|   5 |       456 | /side-build |
+-----+-----------+-------------+
```